# How to implement notification action in api level below 20, just like in watsapp we have reply option which opens up a dialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to implement notification action. My app has minimum api level 15. I want to open a dialog from the notification reply button like it happens in Watsapp. In my device's watsapp this reply option is working which is of API 17. I don't know how watsapp is able to do so because when I am trying  Notification.Action is asking for API 20 or more.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

PendingIntent replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);


 RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder("sdgd")
                .setLabel("sdfdsf")
                .build();


Notification.Action action =
                new Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.img1, getString(R.string.confirmation), replyPendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        .build();
```

Please help me guys and thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080511/how-to-send-reply-from-expandable-notification-in-android